# C++ Windows MFC Concurrency: Get thread to wait until particular state achieved

Tags: c++, c, windows, concurrency, mfc

On Windows MFC concurrency, how do I tell my current thread to wait until a particular state is achieved? The only way I can think of at the moment is to perform periodical Sleep and check the state -- when we're at intended state then continue. Is there any better way of doing this?

```
BOOL achieved = FALSE;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

  // This function creates a new thread and modifies the 'achieved' global variable at some point in the future
  doSomethingOnAnotherThread();

  // Wait maximum 4 seconds for 'achieved' to be TRUE, otherwise give up
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    EnterCriticalSection(&CS);
    int localAchieved = achieved;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&CS);

    if (!localAchieved) { 
      if(i==4) { 
        cout << "waited too long .. giving up" << endl; 
        break; 
      }
      Sleep(1000); // let's wait 1 more second and see what happen
    } else {
      cout << "achieved is TRUE, resuming main thread" << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a [CEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efk30beh(v=vs.100).aspx) would be helpful? Maybe with a `dwTimeout` of `4000`?

Comment: By the way, why use MFC for a console application?

Comment: @Sergey I think he just wanted to provide an example of what he'd already tried

Comment: @JohnSibly, oh, I see the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CEvent Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efk30beh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Represents an event, which is a synchronization object that enables one thread to notify another that an event has occurred.

So, it is the appropriate tool to solve the problem.

Let's illustrate it:

```
void DoSomethingOnAnotherThread(CEvent* event)
{
    // Long-running operation.
    ...

    // Sets the state of the event to signaled, releasing any waiting threads.
    event->SetEvent();

    // TODO: maybe add try/catch and SetEvent() always after the long-running operation???
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Manual-reset event.
    CEvent achieved_event(FALSE, TRUE);

    // This function creates a new thread and modifies the 'achieved' global variable at some point in the future
    DoSomethingOnAnotherThread(&achieved_event);

    // Wait the event to be signalled for 4 seconds!
    DWORD wait_result = WaitForSingleObject(achieved_event, 4000);

    switch (wait_result) {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        std::cout << "Achieved!" << std::endl;
        break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        std::cout << "Timeout!" << std::endl;
        break;
    default: // WAIT_FAILED
        std::cout << "Failed to wait!" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is by far the most convincing solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use are [event objects.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of polling you could use WinAPI: See [CreateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)